# Google Script - Applying part of a 2d array to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a sheet which I've used arrays to retrieve data and do some validations/calculations etc.

At the end of my code, I want to apply the updated values back to the sheet.

I've written this line.

```
shTest.getRange(1,1,sourceArray.length,sourceArray[0].length).setValues(sourceArray);
```

which works perfectly fine in applying the values of the full 2d array (which has 5 columns) to the sheet.

However I want to apply just the 5th column to column E in my sheet shTest (I declared shTest as a variable for my test sheet earlier in the code)

I got as far as this:

```
shTest.getRange(1,5,sourceArray.length,1).setValues(sourceArray);
```

But I couldn't workout how to amend the sourceArray part of my code (after .setValues) to specify that I want the data from the 5 column of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
shTest.getRange(1,5,sourceArray.length,1).setValues(sourceArray);
```

#### To:

```
shTest.getRange(1,5,sourceArray.length,1).setValues(sourceArray.map(r => [r[4]]));
```

- By this modification, the values of column "E" (`the 5 column` in your question) are put to the column "E" of "shTest" sheet.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Michael Liew Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.